# Spark: String to date datatype conversion returning null values

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a dataframe and tring to convert its datatype of some columns so I am using the below function:

```
val rawDF = df.selectExpr(df.columns.map(cn => {
                if (Set("speed", "weight", "height").contains(cn)) s"cast($cn as double) as $cn"
                else if (Set("isActive").contains(cn)) s"cast($cn as date) as $cn"
                else cn
            }):_*)
```

But the problem is: for the date conversion (String to date datatype) I am getting the null values.
My date values are: `31.12.2016`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date string is not in default format. You have to convert into timestamp based on known format.

E.g.:

```
val df = spark.sql("""
  SELECT '31.12.2016' as isActive"""
)

val rawDF = df.selectExpr(df.columns.map(cn => {
                if (Set("speed", "weight", "height").contains(cn)) s"cast($cn as double) as $cn"
                else if (Set("isActive").contains(cn)) s"TO_DATE(CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP($cn, 'dd.MM.yyyy') AS TIMESTAMP)) as $cn"
                else cn
            }):_*)
```

Output:

```
+----------+
|isActive  |
+----------+
|2016-12-31|
+----------+
```

Comment: so what about rest of the columns?? In that case I cave to select column one by one..

Comment: I have updated answer based on selectExpr. If you have more date type column but different format then needs to handle separately.

Comment: It seems it is working fine.. will let you know if I found any issue. Thanks for the kind help and your time.